# Testing client-side javascript code with Jasmine and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests

Given: client-side javascript code (runs in browser, uses jquery etc). Currently the code is tested with `Rhino` and `envjs`. We would like to switch to node.js. However, after some research, couldn't find any `envjs`-like supplementary that emulates a browser.

While running `node.js` "as is", even basic capabilities like `alert()` or `window` are missing.

Is there any standard bundle, similar to `Rhino & envjs` for `node.js` please?

Comment: This is a very underdeveloped part of software.  Took me forever to find a way to even run my JS tests with my other tests in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), which has everything you need for testing. Or you could leverage jsdom (which zombie.js uses internally) to get a DOM in node.js, and execute your tests against that DOM.

I can also recommend [testling](http://testling.com/), which executes tests according to your specification in all common browsers -- the code is running in actual browsers against your service.

Here's a simple example with jsdom:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(url, ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"], function(err, window) {
    // jQuery is at window.$
});
```

Instead of `url` above, you could have an HTML document, or fragment.

You can also load a page and fetch any external resources, instead of providing jQuery etc directly to jsdom:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom,
    doc = jsdom(markup),
    window = doc.createWindow();

// Do your stuff on window, jsdom will have fetched all the scripts referenced in the markup
```

Again, zombie.js uses jsdom internally and it might be a better starting point.

Comment: What's your consumption of testling minutes like? I'm always worried I would run my tests "too much" and consume "too many" minutes

Comment: Raynos: I have actually just tried it out. I'm in the verge of launching and as soon as business takes off, I'm pretty sure testling will be well worth the cost, since I hate manual browser testing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two options for this

1. Your testing browser code. Run it in the browser. Emulating the browser doesn't proof your code works, at all.
2. Use a tool like [phantom](http://www.phantomjs.org/) / [zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)

Of course there are alternatives to this, you can extract any non-browser related code, write a unit test suite for them and run it in node. It's just JavaScript.

You can also use managed services like [testling](http://testling.com/) to run your browser tests for you